# Label cutting off in data driven pages of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, data-driven-pages

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

I've been trying to play around with the Label Manager but can't seem to figure out a solution.  I am trying to label line features in Data Driven Pages and for those lines that are along the border of my map, the label is being shown as half in / half out.

Is there a way to make sure the labels stay completely in the map area, or even completely out?

The picture below shows what I'm looking at.

[image: Label is found within the poorly drawn red circle. It's not entirely visible in the map.]

Comment: Unless you are able to do this for one data frame without Data Driven Pages enabled, I think there is no chance of doing it with Data Driven Pages enabled.  I don't recall ever having seen this done in ArcMap.  However, I *think* I have in ArcGIS Pro, but I may not have had Map Series enabled at the time.

Comment: You can convert labels to annotation feature class in gdb. This will give you full control over every individual label. You can add a page number attribute to each label and only display labels for that page via page definition in the def query tab. Duplicate a label that spans two pages and assign relevant page number to each. So if a label has a page vaule of 2 they will only display when DDPs are on page 2 for example.

Answer (score 1):

On the Labeling toolbar for your map, go to Labeling Options, Maplex tab, and uncheck "Allow labels to overlap border". This is usually off by default in my experience, but I am pretty sure yours got checked on. I have never seen labels get cut off like you describe. Only annotation, database or map, does this normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple pages in DDP, you will need to convert the labels to annotations and enable the "Page Definition" for the annotations (under layer properties > definition query > page definition). Only then you'll have full control over the labels location.